# conditional join sql with validity check

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, transactions

I need to receive a flag from Table2 based on Transaction date ...I have done a left outer join between table 1 and table2. I'm creating 2 calculated fields after the left outer join as:

```
Cal_Validfrom - If Validityfrom is null then 10000101 else Validityfrom end
Cal_ValidTo   - If ValidityTo   is null then 99991231 else Validityfrom end
```

and I'm filter on the calculated fields and transaction date

Case1)

```
Table 1 ->  Transaction ID   Transaction Date   Price
              123             02/15/2017        $100
Table 2  -> Transaction ID   ValidityFrom  ValidityTo  Flag
               123            01/01/2017   01/15/2017   A
               123            01/16/2017   02/01/2017   B 
               123            02/02/2017   12/31/9999   C
```

After the join

```
     Transaction ID    Transaction Date   Price    ValidityFrom  ValidityTo  Flag   Cal_Validfrom Cal_ValidTo
           123           02/15/2017        $100     01/01/2017   01/15/2017   A       01/01/2017   01/15/2017
           123           02/15/2017        $100     01/16/2017   02/01/2017   B       01/16/2017   02/01/2017
           123           02/15/2017        $100     02/02/2017   12/31/9999   C       02/02/2017   12/31/9999
```

Then Filter on  Cal_Validfrom <= Transaction Date  <= Cal_ValidTo

```
     Transaction ID    Transaction Date   Price    ValidityFrom  ValidityTo  Flag   Cal_Validfrom Cal_ValidTo
           123           02/15/2017        $100     02/02/2017   12/31/9999   C       02/02/2017   12/31/9999
```

Case2)

```
Table 1 ->  Transaction ID   Transaction Date   Price
              123             02/15/2017        $100   
Table 2  -> ValidityFrom  ValidityTo
No Records
```

After the join

```
     Transaction ID    Transaction Date   Price    ValidityFrom  ValidityTo  Flag   Cal_Validfrom Cal_ValidTo
           123           02/15/2017        $100     Null          Null       Null    01/01/1000   12/31/9999
```

Then Filter on  Cal_Validfrom <= Transaction Date  <= Cal_ValidTo

```
     Transaction ID    Transaction Date   Price    ValidityFrom  ValidityTo  Flag   Cal_Validfrom Cal_ValidTo
           123           02/15/2017        $100     Null          Null       Null    01/01/1000   12/31/9999
```

Case3)

```
Table 1 ->  Transaction ID   Transaction Date   Price
              123             02/15/2017        $100

Table 2  -> Transaction ID   ValidityFrom  ValidityTo  Flag
               123            01/01/2017   01/15/2017   A
               123            01/16/2017   02/01/2017   B
```

After the join

```
     Transaction ID    Transaction Date   Price    ValidityFrom  ValidityTo  Flag   Cal_Validfrom Cal_ValidTo
           123           02/15/2017        $100     01/01/2017   01/15/2017   A       01/01/2017   01/15/2017
           123           02/15/2017        $100     01/16/2017   02/01/2017   B       01/16/2017   02/01/2017
```

Then Filter on  Cal_Validfrom <= Transaction Date  <= Cal_ValidTo

```
     Transaction ID    Transaction Date   Price    ValidityFrom  ValidityTo  Flag   Cal_Validfrom Cal_ValidTo
```

The Problem is with Case 3 - I Still need to see the transaction - I cannot loose the transaction or duplicate the transaction.

Any Suggestions

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using sql server procedure

Comment: Could you not left join `table1` to this result, selecting only rows where `Transaction ID` is null in the result, and `UNION` that with the original results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you filter AFTER the join, which potentially eliminates the transaction record.
In order to solve this, you need to do a left outer join, with a table that has already been filtered, let's call that table table2'.
Table2' is the result of a (normal) join between table2 and table1, where you apply the filter. Because you did not provide a schema, I'll illustrate with this:

```
select t1.[Transaction ID], t1.[Transaction Date], t1.[Price], 
       t2.[Transaction ID], t2.ValidityFrom , t2.ValidityTo,  t2.Flag
from table1 t1
    left outer join table2 t2 on t1.[Transaction ID] = t2.[Transaction ID]
where 
    t2.ValidityFrom <= [Transaction Date]  
    and [Transaction Date] <= t2.ValidityTo


-- SHOULD BECOME:


select t1.[Transaction ID], t1.[Transaction Date], t1.[Price], 
       t2.[Transaction ID], t2.ValidityFrom , t2.ValidityTo,  t2.Flag
from table1 t1
    left outer join 
    (   select t22.[Transaction ID], t22.ValidityFrom , t22.ValidityTo,  t22.Flag
        from table2 t22 join table1 t11 on t11.[Transaction ID] = t22.[Transaction ID]
        where 
            t22.ValidityFrom <= [Transaction Date]  
            and [Transaction Date] <= t22.ValidityTo    
    ) t2
```